# Error message "no allocator statistics" after installing cuDNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

On CPU I am able to use TensorFlow correctly, but after installing cuDNN in an attempt to get my GTX 1060 GPU working as my hardware for networks, I am getting an error when I try to do the simplest things, like initializing a `Sequential`.

I have tried reinstalling all of CUDA, etc. but I am unable to fix this. I am currently using CUDA 11.2 based on someone else's solution to a problem that sounded similar.

Here is the full error, reproduced without any greater context:

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-08-14 21:55:22.548144: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
>>> test = tf.keras.Sequential()
2021-08-14 21:55:31.641066: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.661733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.8095GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2021-08-14 21:55:31.661884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.669095: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.669242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.673384: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.674833: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.680408: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.683701: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.684489: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-14 21:55:31.684674: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-14 21:55:31.685108: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-08-14 21:55:31.685740: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.8095GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2021-08-14 21:55:31.685976: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-14 21:55:32.172118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-14 21:55:32.172274: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-08-14 21:55:32.173006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-08-14 21:55:32.173448: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_process_state.cc:210] Using CUDA malloc Async allocator for GPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 114, in __init__
    super(functional.Functional, self).__init__(  # pylint: disable=bad-super-call
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 318, in __init__
    self._init_batch_counters()
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 326, in _init_batch_counters
    self._train_counter = variables.Variable(0, dtype='int64', aggregation=agg)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 244, in _variable_v2_call
    return previous_getter(
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 237, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2662, in default_variable_creator_v2
    return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 264, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1584, in __init__
    self._init_from_args(
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1727, in _init_from_args
    initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(initial_value,
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1566, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 264, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 276, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 301, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 97, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    ctx.ensure_initialized()
  File "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 525, in ensure_initialized
    context_handle = pywrap_tfe.TFE_NewContext(opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: No allocator statistics
```

Really tearing out my hair with this one, especially because I was able to use my GPU for TensorFlow recently, until it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the use of the env variable TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async as discussed here
[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48545](http://%20https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48545)